# Ability to determine which PGP public keys a message has been encrypted for?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, pgp, gnupg

Is it possible to determine, given a PGP message that you can already decrypt, to determine which other PGP keys that message has also been encrypted for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, although you used [pgp](/questions/tagged/pgp), I assume you will actually be using  GnuPG. Otherwise, fetch it - it's free software. Although PGP will probably also have similar functionality.

### Hidden Recipients

It depends. If the sender included the recipient's key fingerprints, you can retrieve them; otherwise (if encrypted using the `--hidden-recipient` option) GnuPG has to test all your private decryption keys against the message.

### Listing (non-Hidden) Recipients

If the recipients are included, GnuPG will list them when set to verbose mode (`--verbose`). To prevent GnuPG from actually decrypting the message, add `--list-only`. The relevant lines are the ones starting with `gpg: public key is`.

This will output public subkeys, which you have to resolve again using `gpg --list-keys [key-id]`.

A complete command line to retrieve the recipients from a message:

```
cat message.pgp | LANG=C gpg --verbose --list-only 2>&1 | grep 'gpg: public key is'
```

If you even want to automatically resolve subkeys, additionally pipe through `cut` and `xargs`:

```
cat message.pgp | LANG=C gpg --verbose --list-only 2>&1 | grep 'gpg: public key is' | cut -d' ' -f 5 | xargs gpg --list-keys
```

`LANG=C` is used to enforce English localization, so `grep`ping will not fail for other languages.